# How to hook up user-wide integration of custom C++ libraries in Visual Sudios like vcpkg?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, vcpkg

I have several third party libraries (both static  and dynamic).

Its becoming cumbersome and error-prone to add path every time in different project/builds.

Is their a way by I can hook up user-wide integration of custom C++ libraries in Visual Sudios like the one used by vcpkg.

In vcpkg I just select appropriate build configuration and appropriate library gets selected.

I am using using Visual Studios 2017 on Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: If you like vcpkg then [just use it](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/about/faq.md), "private library" sections.  But do consider to look at what View > Other Windows > Property Manager and Project > Export Template can do for you.

Comment: @HansPassant, Sir, can you elaborate on last part `View > Other Windows > Property Manager and Project > Export Template`.

Comment: Press F1 to learn more about them.